# Angular Js how to show dynamic content

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am completely new to ANgularJs. As part of one project my page should show some content dynamically is changes in database. This changed vale can be obtained by a http get.

Before I try the complete scenario, I just wanted to see if is working atleast locally by taking a local variable. But its not working please suggest me how do I handle this.

```
angular.module('MyApp')  .controller('HomeCtrl', function HomeCtrl($scope, $alert, $auth,$location) {
Counter=10;
Counter=Counter+1;
$scope.user={};
$scope.user.counter=Counter;
 }
HomeCtrl($scope,$alert,$auth,$location);
);
```

Comment: I think that you are just bit confused about using an AngularJS controller. Please refers to https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02 official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to remove the following line:

```
HomeCtrl($scope,$alert,$auth,$location);
```

As you are still in the controller function call

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how do I make this code execute recursively in order to get the new value.

Comment: Why would you want this code to be recursive? If you want it to periodically update, you could use $timeout - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
HomeCtrl($scope,$alert,$auth,$location);
```

but there were some other things also wrong..

working version:
fiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/beLbv6L1/

Comment: But I don't want to add a button and also the click event. The loop should increment the value and should be dynamically displayed on the screen with out a page refresh or any other events(ex:Mouse click)